# Polymer how to render <template> asynchronous without affecting interaction with user

Tags: javascript, polymer

My page have several huge `<template>`, only will be render and show in any time. But when changing `<template>` to render, it takes too long. For example:

```
<polymer-element name = "my-element">
  <template>
   <template if = "{{render == '#1'}}">
      <!--Many elements, takes long time to render-->
   </template>
   <template if = "{{render == '#2'}}">
      <!--Many elements, takes very long time to render-->
   </template>
   <paper-button on-click = "{{changeRender}}"></paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      render: '#1',
      changeRender: function() {
        this.render = '#2';
     }
    });
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

When user clicks button, the ripple of paper shows up but stuck and stay until `<template if = "{{render == '#2'}}">` rendered. I've tried to change code to this:

```
changeRender: function() {
  var obj = this;
  this.async(function() {
    obj.render = '#2';
  }, null, 300);
}
```

It won't stuck now but the time delay is a bit unfriendly to users, does anyone has a better solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems related to https://github.com/Polymer/paper-ripple/issues/10.

One thing you can do is wait for the ripple animation to finish before activating the template:

```
<paper-button on-core-transitionend="{{changeRender}}"></paper-button>

changeRender: function() {
  this.render = '#2';
}
```

Comment: Thans, but users still need to wait until the ripple faded, is there a better solution that page start to change once the button is clicked? By the way, the document of <paper-ripple> miss events it may fire.